# Determining which polygons a point is within from a large set of polygons

Tags: geometry, polygon, point, vertex, polygons

Say I have a 2D plane, covered with polygons (identified as an array of vertexes), analogous to:

[image]

Lets say I also have a point with coordinates on this plane, what is the easiest method to return which of the polygons the point is present in?

Although this example lists 4 polygons, it would be simple to run a [check on each polygon to see if the point is within it](http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/), but I am building a system that presently has about 150 polygons, and could extend up to thousands, so doing it that way could become very slow.

So, are there any solutions to doing this that do not incur iterating through all available polygons, and checking if the point is present?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kd-tree or a r-tree. It can reduces the search space. You can also  look for a quadtree. You can choose the quad size to fit the polygons and to minimize overlapping bounding boxes.

Comment: Wow, that looks perfect, I'm searching for info about that now, but do you know of any resources that would show this being implemented, pseudo code if possible, but I'm fairly language agnostic and can interpret

Comment: I wrote a quadkey solution. It uses a hilbert curve and it's similar to a quadtree. You can download it at phpclasses.org. But it's not hard to code a kd-tree. You can also use a database with a spatial index.